# Is there anyone who got their psychic power through science?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index, a-certain-scientific-railgun

On the first episode of To Aru Majutsu No Index, Touma said

> Magic is impossible, psychic powers aren't even rare at this city school. Anyone can invent it with the powers of science.

And Touma himself said that he got his power since he was born.

So, is there anyone in Index and Railgun who become an esper using science?

Note: I haven't finished watching Index, but I've watch Railgun, and I don't think there's anyone able to do this.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask here... Almost all supernatural ability users in Academic City are "artificially" created through the [Power Curriculum Program](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Curriculum_Program) of Academic City. Those rare, natural ability users are called "[Gemstones](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Gemstone)."

Comment: Really? I don't know about that. Did they explain it in Index? Or am I missing something in Railgun? I only watch about 10 eps in Index

Comment: Railgun is specific to the Science Side. Index tends to skew towards the Magic Side, but there is overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most psychic powers are created by science. Normally, an Esper doesn't have a special ability and only gains it by experiments, special drugs etc. See [Power Curriculum Program](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Curriculum_Program) for more information.

There are some (at the moment 4 known of which only 3 occur in the original works) people who have esper-abilities without being part of the Power Curriculum Program, called [Gemstones](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Gemstone). The only one that occurred in the anime yet is Himegami Aisa (appeared in Index Episode 7 (Deep Blood Arc)).

Touma himself has no psychic power, his power is of unknown source.

Thanks to Krazer for mentioning the Gemstones in the comments.

Comment: Touma's power isn't considered an psychic power because he doesn't emit an AIM field which espers and gemstones  do.